# Laravel query builder how to write orderBy query having CAST and REPLACE functions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i have a query like this

`SELECT area FROM history_cost_estimation ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(area, ' ', '') AS INT)`

i'm trying to translate such query into laravel query builder but i got many errors

this is my try

```
App\Models\HistoryCostEstimation::orderBy("CAST(REPLACE(area, ' ', '') AS INT)",'asc')->count();
```

and here is sample of the error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `)` asc' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `engineertec`.`history_cost_estimation` order by `CAST(REPLACE(area,` as `)` asc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the DB facade and use raw mysql

make sure to add the DB facade to the controller or wherever you are running this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

then do

```
DB::table('history_cost_estimation')->select('area')->orderBy(DB::raw('CAST(REPLACE(area, ' ', ''), 'INT')));
```